# Heroku application error - rails/commands/server.rb:12:in `parse!': missing argument: -e (OptionParser::MissingArgument)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to deploy a rails app on heroku.

Deploying works fine and I can run heroku console without problems,

However when I try to run the app on heroku I get an application error:

```
Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

if I try to run the app locally with heroku local, I get this:

```
web.1  | /Users/snowflakekiller/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:12:in `parse!': missing argument: -e (OptionParser::MissingArgument)
web.1  |    from /Users/snowflakekiller/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `new'
```

this is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'bootstrap_form'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem "rmagick", :require => 'RMagick'
gem 'ckeditor'
gem 'acts_as_commentable'
gem 'addressable'
gem 'vimeo'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'pry'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'

end
```

this is my heroku log:

```
2015-12-09T16:53:28.606103+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-12-09T16:53:28.606110+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-12-09T16:53:28.606105+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-12-09T16:53:29.326350+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-12-09T16:53:31.608084+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sickbubble.herokuapp.com request_id=dffabe0d-b895-4d50-8dfc-bb09f8878c4e fwd="175.139.1.56" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

my procfile looks like this

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV
```

any ideas? The fact that it deploys successfully and I can run heroku rails console is throwing me off

Comment: What does your Procfile look like?

Comment: @WizardofOgz added the procfile to original quesiton, thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I... didn't have `gem 'thin'` in my gemfile. oops.

Comment: glad you figured it out :D

Comment: @ksokol How does this not provide an answer?

Comment: @ksokol what do you mean? That was the answer... I was missing gem 'thin' in my gemfile.....